# Setting autoindentation to spaces in neovim?

Tags: vim, neovim

I was wondering how I could set the autoindentation to four spaces upon startup in neovim, because I use spaces for indentation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I don’t know Neovim specifically, but (from what I read [there](https://www.reddit.com/r/neovim/comments/2zpad3/has_neovim_changed_any_pasteindentation_option/)) I guess that it is compatible with Vim on this topic. So explanations below apply to pure Vim.

The option you are looking for is `'expandtab'`. However, for clarity, I explain indenting width before going into this option.

## Indenting width(s)

The *width* of an indentation is controlled by several options. By “indenting”, here, I mean for example pressing `<Tab>` in Insert Mode (or `<BS>`, backspace, which undoes an existing indentation), or increasing the indenting level automatically (depending on the language).

```
:help tabstop
:help softtabstop
:help shiftwidth
```

The integer option **`'tabstop'`** dictates the width used to display an actual tabulation character (`\t`) (not directly what you are interested in, but see below).

The integer option **`'softtabstop'`** says how wide an indentation is supposed to span. The special value 0 means to replicate the value of `'tabstop'` (or more exactly, to disable the “soft tab stops” feature), the special value −1 means to replicate the value of `'shiftwidth'`.

The integer option **`'shiftwidth'`** gives the width used for shifting commands, such as `<<`, `>>` and `==`. The special value 0 means to replicate the value of `'tabstop'`.

## Indenting with spaces

When **`'expandtab'`** is set, indenting is always done using space characters only. Otherwise, pressing `<Tab>` inserts as many tabulation characters as possible, and complete with space characters up to the indenting width.

```
:help expandtab
```

## An illustration

For example, if `tabstop=8` and `softtabstop=3`, then, in Insert Mode:

1. pressing `<Tab>` on an empty line will insert 3 spaces, so that the total indentation is 3‐column wide;
2. pressing `<Tab>` again will insert 3 more spaces, so that the total indentation is 6‐column wide;
3. pressing `<Tab>` will make the total indentation 9‐column wide; if `'expandtab'` is set, then it will be written using a total of 9 spaces; otherwise, it will be written using a tabulation character (which replaces former whitespaces) followed by a space character;
4. pressing `<BS>` will undo step 3;
5. pressing `<BS>` will undo step 2;
6. pressing `<BS>` will undo step 1.

## Example configuration

Most often, you want to make it simple and have the same value for the three width options. Here is a example configuration that identifies all three options, so that you just need to change the value of `'tabstop'` to your liking. It also sets `'expandtab'` as you requested. Finally, since you evoked auto‐indentation, I included related options: `'autoindent'`, `'smartindent'` and `'cindent'`; but you should rather use language‐specific plugins for that.

```
" length of an actual \t character:
set tabstop=4
" length to use when editing text (eg. TAB and BS keys)
" (0 for ‘tabstop’, -1 for ‘shiftwidth’):
set softtabstop=-1
" length to use when shifting text (eg. <<, >> and == commands)
" (0 for ‘tabstop’):
set shiftwidth=0
" round indentation to multiples of 'shiftwidth' when shifting text
" (so that it behaves like Ctrl-D / Ctrl-T):
set shiftround

" if set, only insert spaces; otherwise insert \t and complete with spaces:
set expandtab

" reproduce the indentation of the previous line:
set autoindent
" keep indentation produced by 'autoindent' if leaving the line blank:
"set cpoptions+=I
" try to be smart (increase the indenting level after ‘{’,
" decrease it after ‘}’, and so on):
"set smartindent
" a stricter alternative which works better for the C language:
"set cindent
" use language‐specific plugins for indenting (better):
filetype plugin indent on
```

You can tweak these settings and write them down in your `.vimrc` or `.nvimrc` file.

Of course, additionally, you can select specific settings for each buffer, based on its filetype. For example:

```
" do NOT expand tabulations in Makefiles:
autocmd FileType make setlocal noexpandtab

" for the C language, indent using 4‐column wide tabulation characters,
" but make <Tab> insert half‐indentations as 2 spaces (useful for labels):
autocmd FileType c setlocal noexpandtab shiftwidth=2

" use shorter indentation for Bash scripts:
autocmd FileType sh setlocal tabstop=2
```

Comment: Yup, completely compatible on this and many other fronts. Since you provide such a comprehensive answer, you might also be interested in `'shiftround'`, even if it's not directly related to the question.

Answer (score 13):

If you want to use 2 spaces indentation, put this in your config:

```
set tabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2
set expandtab
set smartindent
```

Answer (score 13):

Lua:

```lua
local o = vim.o

o.expandtab = true # expand tab input with spaces characters
o.smartindent = true # syntax aware indentations for newline inserts
o.tabstop = 2 # num of space characters per tab
o.shiftwidth = 2 # spaces per indentation level
```

[An article explaining tab settings](https://arisweedler.medium.com/tab-settings-in-vim-1ea0863c5990#:%7E:text=expandtab%20%E2%80%94%20Unlike%20the%20other%20settings,tab%20key%20and%20backspace%20key.)